# Increase distance when draw a ellipse

Tags: c#, drawing, ellipse

How can i increase the distance when i draw a ellipse from a certain point?
This is the code i use to draw a ellipse in c#:

```
public double[] CalculatePosition(double centerX, double centerY, double angle)
{
    double[] position = new double[2];
    position[0] = Math.Cos(angle) * radiusX + centerX;
    position[1] = Math.Sin(angle) * radiusY + centerY;
    return position;
}
```

draw a ellipse based on a point. the function that use this, draw for example 5 ellipses, around the point.

Comment: I can't tell if it is a question about programming or math? If this is for drawing why not return a `PointF` structure instead of `double[]`?

Comment: is a little of both. what i mean is the distance to the center, for example the distance is to small and now only feat around it 5 ellipse, so i whant to increase the distance to the center so can feat more ellipse around a point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean the size of the eclipse? In which case, you want to vary radiusX and radiusY.

The best way to do this is to pass them as parameters to the function:

```
public double[] CalculatePosition(double centerX, 
                                 double centerY, 
                                 double radiusX,
                                 double radiusY,
                                 double angle)
{
    double[] position = new double[2];
    position[0] = Math.Cos(angle) * radiusX + centerX;
    position[1] = Math.Sin(angle) * radiusY + centerY;
    return position;
}
```

Then you can draw several ellipses around the same point by calling this function several times, and varying radiusX and radiusY.

Comment: no, is not the size, is the distance from to the point, so we can have more ellipse around a point, the distance now is too small, only feat 5 ellipse, so i whant to increase the distance to the point so we can have for example 10 ellipse